# Emulating book-class-sectioning using titlesec and modifiying it

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

**In short:**

- Prerequisite: Need to emulate book-class for `\part` and `\chapter` using `titlesec`
- Change both to hang, start on same page
- Add `titlerule` to `\chapter`

---

I want to optimize my rather hacked template.

First, as it isn't possible to do the changes below using `titlesec` without defining the sectioning title/head as a whole, I need it to be exactly like predefined by the standard `book`-class. That needs to be the starting point.

Then I want to use `titlesec` to make `\part` and `\chapter` "hanged" (like `\titleformat{\part}[hang]`) and on the same page with the following chaptertext:

Not this:

```
      Part A     
     Parttitle

-------newpage--------
Chapter 1

Chaptertitle
```

but this:

```
A Parttitle

1 Chaptertitle
```

At last I need to replace the following newcommand

```
\newcommand{\addchapterunderline}{\vspace{-4ex}\hrule height 1.5pt \vspace{7ex}\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

for `\chapter` AND `\chapter*`, wich I utilized like this until now:

```
\chapter[Test]{Test}
\addchapterunderline
```

The final structure should look like this using `\titlerule[1.5pt]`:

```
A Parttitle

B Chaptertitle
________________________

Lorem ipsum ...
```

In this example I already tried my best (<-- still beginner). But I cannot prove whether this is `book`-class-like with only my changes above, as I could not find the heading-definitions in the `book.cls`:

```
\documentclass{book}

        \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}
        \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}      
        \usepackage{tgheros}                            
        \usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}     
        \usepackage{amssymb}                            
        \usepackage{ae,aecompl}                     
        \usepackage{charter}                            

%\newcommand{\addchapterunderline}{\vspace{-4ex}\hrule height 1.5pt \vspace{7ex}\thispagestyle{empty}} %I don't want to use this

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}[hang]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge} % global formatting (number and title) 
    {\thepart} 
    {20pt} %spacing between number and title
    {\huge}
\titlespacing*{\part}
   {0pt}% left
   {1cm}% before
   {1.2em}% after
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge} % global formatting (number and title)
    {\thechapter}  % label: number and its formatting
    {20pt} %spacing between number and title
    {\huge}[\vspace{2ex}{\titlerule[1.5pt]}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
   {0pt}% left
   {1cm}% before
   {6.2em}% after



\begin{document}
\part{This is a Testpart}
\chapter{This is a Testchapter}
\chapter*{This is a unnumbered Testchapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Section 9.2 of the `titlesec` manual shows how to emulate the sectioning commands of the standard classes.

Comment: Really helpful, but the definition for `\part` is missing. Where can I find this?

Comment: Sadly, I don't know.

Comment: And what should happen with other chapters of the same part? Should the same formatting  also apply to them? I mean, chapter two of the first part should have the title immediately after the end of chapter one without issuing the default `\cleardoublepage`?

Comment: No, @Gonzalo, of course I manually add `\newpage{\thispagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage}` after every chapter.

Comment: @FLW so, does my answer do something similir to what you need?

Comment: @FLW please see my updated answer; now you don't have to issue manually the commands `\newpage...\cleardoublepage`; it can be automatically done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no information on the formatting for other chapters in the same part, so I assumed they should all have the same behaviour (in particular, they should not start on a new odd page); there was also no information on the vertical space before part titles, so I assumed some settings (which can be easily changed, if necessary). Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}

\titleformat{\part}[hang]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thepart}
  {1em}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}
  {1em}{\Huge}[\vskip8pt{\titlerule[1.5pt]}]

\titlespacing*{\part}
  {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}

\part{Test Part One}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After a comment to the original question, only the first chapter should have the mentioned behaviour; other chapters of a same part should issue the standard `\cleardoublepage` command from book.cls; this can be automatically achieved using a conditional test and the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}

\titleformat{\part}[hang]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedright}{\thepart}
  {1em}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\raggedright}{\thechapter}
  {1em}{\Huge}[\vskip8pt{\titlerule[1.5pt]}]

\titlespacing*{\part}
  {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\pretocmd{\chapter}{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \newpage\thispagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage\else\fi}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\part{Charakterisierung des französischen Automobilwesens in Berlin} \chapter{Charakterisierung des französischen Automobilwesens in Berlin} \chapter{Charakterisierung des französischen Automobilwesens in Berlin}

\end{document}
```

An image of the first page containing the part title:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is it. But now I encounter overfull lines: ![prob](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=9136269583911)

Comment: @FLW are those overfull lines directly related to the titles? If so, I would need to see a simple document using my code and producing the problem mentioned.

Comment: Please use this in your example above to reproduce:

`\part{Charakterisierung des französischen Automobilwesens in Berlin}
\chapter{Charakterisierung des französischen Automobilwesens in Berlin}
\chapter{Charakterisierung des französischen Automobilwesens in Berlin}`

Comment: @FLW you can then use `\raggedright` as I did in my updated answer; this will also prevent hyphenations, which don't look good in titles.

Comment: Works great. Regarding your `\pretocmd{\chapter}{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \newpage\thispagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage\else\fi}{}{}{}` I had to use my old solution because `\part` was on its own page again using your solution. But that is ok. Thanks again.