# Transfering Style of Sectioning-Titles to TOC-, LOF-, LOT-Titles

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, titlesec, tocloft, titletoc

This is a continuation of my last (answered) [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101356/emulating-book-class-sectioning-using-titlesec-and-modifiying-it):

I want to style the Title of TOC, LOF and LOT exactly the same as the Sectioning-Titles. Problem is that they (a) start "higher" than normal `\chapter`-titles (means the space between "page head" and title body is smaller) and (b) the space between the title body and the titlerule is noticably varying.

Example (current progress):

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}

        \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}
        \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}      
        \usepackage{tgheros}                            
        \usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}     
        \usepackage{amssymb}                            
        \usepackage{ae,aecompl}                     
        \usepackage{charter}                            



%-------Styling of Titles-------%
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}

\titleformat{\part}[hang]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge\raggedright}{\thepart}
  {20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge\raggedright}{\thechapter}
  {20pt}{\Huge}[\vskip8pt{\titlerule[1.5pt]}]

\titlespacing*{\part}
  {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

%--------------------------------%

%-------Styling of TOC-, LOT-, LOF-Titles-------------------------%
    \usepackage{tocloft}
%------ TOC ---------------------------------------%
        \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge} 
                \addtolength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{4.0ex}
                \renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{
    \vskip8pt{\titlerule[1.5pt]
    %           \vspace{4.5ex}
    %           \hrule height 1.5pt
    %           \vspace{-2.6ex
                }}
    %------LOF-----------%
        \renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge}
                \addtolength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{4.0ex}
                \renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{
    \vskip8pt{\titlerule[1.5pt]
    %           \vspace{3.2ex} 
    %           \hrule height 1.5pt
    %           \vspace{-2.6ex
                }}
    %------LOT----------%       
        \renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge} 
                \addtolength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{4.2ex} % o,2 Differenz zu anderen beiden Überschriften ist seltsamerweise notwendig...
                \renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{
    \vskip8pt{\titlerule[1.5pt]
    %           \vspace{4.0ex}
    %           \hrule height 1.5pt
    %           \vspace{-2.6ex
                }}

    \begin{document}

        \newpage

    \tableofcontents

        \newpage

        \listoftables

        \newpage

        \listoffigures

        \newpage

\chapter{Test}

Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus


        \begin{table}[bp]
            \centering
                %\begin{tabular}

                %\end{tabular}
            \caption{Testtable}
            \label{tab:Testtable}
        \end{table}


        \begin{figure}[bp]
            \centering
                %\includegraphics{}
            \caption{Testfigure}
            \label{testfigure}
        \end{figure}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: In an unmodified `book` class there is no special formatting for TOC titles, it simply explicitly calls `\chapter*{\contentsname` so any formatting set up for unnumbered chapters `\chapter*` should apply. If the packages you are loading are making that not true, perhaps they are not helping?

Comment: A justified question but I need the `tocloft`-package to modify the TOC-listings and the `titlesec`-package to modify the sectioning-titles. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: oh there's always a way to make things work, I don't know that package though:-)

Comment: Seems the `tocloft`-package is the cause. Perhaps I can substitute `tocloft` with `titletoc` - I'll try that, although judging from the documentation I'll probably open a new question for this, after trying my own skill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use the `titles` package option for tocloft:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

This option option causes the titles of the ToC, LoF, and LoT lists to be
typeset using the modified titles. A complete example with your code:

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

        \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}             
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}
        \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}      
        \usepackage{tgheros}                            
        \usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}     
        \usepackage{amssymb}                            
        \usepackage{ae,aecompl}                     
        \usepackage{charter}                            



%-------Styling of Titles-------%
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}

\titleformat{\part}[hang]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge\raggedright}{\thepart}
  {20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge\raggedright}{\thechapter}
  {20pt}{\Huge}[\vskip8pt{\titlerule[1.5pt]}]

\titlespacing*{\part}
  {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{20pt}


\begin{document}

        \newpage

    \tableofcontents

        \newpage

        \listoftables

        \newpage

        \listoffigures

        \newpage

\chapter{Test}

Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus


        \begin{table}[bp]
            \centering
                %\begin{tabular}

                %\end{tabular}
            \caption{Testtable}
            \label{tab:Testtable}
        \end{table}


        \begin{figure}[bp]
            \centering
                %\includegraphics{}
            \caption{Testfigure}
            \label{testfigure}
        \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It's an unfortunate choice of `tocloft` to change by default the making of titles and to offer the `titles` option for avoiding it; the option name is misleading, at least. I'd much prefer the `titles` option switched to the modified titles.

Comment: @egreg yes, I agree. In my opinion, the default behaviour should be to honor possible modifications to the titles.