# Alignment of Part and Chapter headings text

Tags: spacing, sectioning, horizontal-alignment, chapters, titlesec

Following [this question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101356/emulating-book-class-sectioning-using-titlesec-and-modifiying-it), I try to make the start of part and chapter title headings "vertically parallel" (right term?).

Example of what I get: ("." not visible only to show space difference)

```
A...PARTTITEL
1..CHAPTERITEL
```

What I aim for:

```
A..PARTTITEL
1..CHAPTERITEL
```

Please see the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}

\titleformat{\part}[hang]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thepart}
  {20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}
  {20pt}{\Huge}[\vskip8pt{\titlerule[1.5pt]}]

\titlespacing*{\part}
  {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}

\part{Test Part One}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the numbers in a fixed width box:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}

\titleformat{\part}[hang]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thepart}}
  {0pt}
  {\Huge}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thechapter}}
  {0pt}
  {\Huge}
  [\vskip8pt{\titlerule[1.5pt]}]

\titlespacing*{\part}
  {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}

\part{Test Part One}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}

\end{document}
```

Adjust `1.5em` to suit (it should be wider, probably, if you have more than nine chapters).

[image]

Not that I find this style particularly attractive. `;-)`

Comment: Appreciate your personal comment on the style, care to recommend your favorites?